# Moving list elements to dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have first names stored in a list `['Bob', 'Matt', 'Tim']`

I'm trying to iterate over the list and add the names to a dictionary.
I want it to go through and add each first name to its own dictionary

```
{first name : 'Bob'} {first name : 'Matt'} {first name : 'Tim'}
```

This is what I'm trying to use

```
names = {}

i = 0
while i < (len(first_names)):
    names.update(first_names[i])
    i += 1
```

but I keep getting the error message

```
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

Comment: @loulou `key`s are unique in a `dict` so this will only have the last element in `first_names` as it will overwrite all the previous names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want a list of dictionaries. In this case you could do this:

```
nameList = ['john','rob','ben']
names =  [{'first name':i} for i in nameList]
```

Which gives:

```
[{'first name': 'john'}, {'first name': 'rob'}, {'first name': 'ben'}]
```